# Merged a branch with gitignored files, can't find those files anymore

Tags: git, github, git-branch, missing-data

I had large log files in a project, so I added the log directory to .gitignore after I had already made a few logs (so there's a log file directory with only a few old logs in my git, all new ones are ignored). I had more logs in a branch and merged it with my master, along with another branch I had been working on. Now the newer logs don't show up in the master, and when I switch back to my branch they're not there either. Is there any way to recover these?